# Removing duplicate code from Spring job configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Below is my step configuration -

```
<beans:bean id="myInputFileReader" class="com.rbos.fm.risk.batch.spring.reader.InputFileReader" scope="step">
        <beans:property name="delegate">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
                    scope="step">
                <beans:property name="resource" ref="inputFileSystemResource" />
                <beans:property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
                <beans:property name="lineMapper">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                        <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
                            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                                <beans:property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
                            </beans:bean>
                        </beans:property>
                        <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                            <beans:bean class="com.test.MyFieldMapper1" scope="prototype"/>
                        </beans:property>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="param1" value="#{jobParameters['param1']}"/>
        <beans:property name="param2" value="#{jobParameters['param2']}"/>
        <beans:property name="param3" value="#{jobParameters['param3']}"/>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="fileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <beans:property name="resource" ref="outputFileSystemResource" />
        <beans:property name="lineAggregator">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <beans:property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
                <beans:property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <beans:property name="names" 
                        value="outcolomn1, outcolomn2, outcolomn3, outcolomn4"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <step id="myPreProcessing1">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk reader="myInputFileReader" processor="myFileProcessor1" writer="fileItemWriter"
                commit-interval="10000"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
```

I have to add other (similar) steps. I would like to use same readers and writers as only change in reader will be a new `FieldSetMapper` and writer will be a new `BeanWrapperFieldExtractor`. So ideally, I would like to specify a reader and writer on parent level and would like to refer them in all the steps by just overriding new mapper and extractor.

Comment: Create a bean definition, set `abstract=true` for the actual bean definitions add `parent="id-of-abstract"` and override/configure further there.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and you can override (AFAIK) only immediate child e.g. delegate in myInputFileReader. In this case I would like to only override fieldSetMapper which is 4 level down (myInputFileReader -> delegate -> lineMapper -> fieldSetMapper).

Comment: Then create 2 parents add another for the `LineMapper` and reference that inside your other definition. It works for nested beans as well. Note the `scope="prototype"` isn't doing anything as it is an inner bean it automatically has the same scope as the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Bean Definition Inheritance](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-child-bean-definitions). Create an abstract bean definition and have your actual definitions use this as a `parent`.

```
<beans:bean id="parentInputFileReader" class="com.rbos.fm.risk.batch.spring.reader.InputFileReader" scope="step" abstract="true">
    <beans:property name="delegate">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
            <beans:property name="resource" ref="inputFileSystemResource" />
            <beans:property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="param1" value="#{jobParameters['param1']}"/>
    <beans:property name="param2" value="#{jobParameters['param2']}"/>
    <beans:property name="param3" value="#{jobParameters['param3']}"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="parentLineMapper" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper" abstract="true">
    <beans:property name="lineTokenizer">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
            <beans:property name="delimiter" value="|"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Now that you have parent beans you can reference them using the `parent` attribute and only configure those properties that are needed or need to be modified from the default.

```
<bean id="myInputFileReader" parent="parent">
    <beans:property name="lineMapper">
        <bean parent="parentLineMapper" >
            <beans:property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <beans:bean class="com.test.MyFieldMapper1" />
            </beans:property>
        </bean>
    </beans:property />
</bean>
```